# Emissive power of a blackbody

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

I have a doubt in this question from iit jee 2000.
Here, the plot is of spectral intensity vs. Wavelength graph of 3 blackbodies.
[image: the image]
And the answer is: T1>T2>T3 and the justification is given by Wien's displacement law. I do understand that solution.

But here's my question:
The area under the curve 2 greater than 3 which in turn is greater than 1. And the area under the spectral intensity vs. wavelength graph gives us the “Emissive power”(power radiated by the blackbody per unit area) and Emissive power is proportional to the fourth power of the temperature of the blackbody (According to Stefan's law).
So according to Stefan's law, the temperature T2>T3>T1. But that is not the right answer.
What exactly am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Stefan–Boltzmann law gives you the radiative power *per area* at a given temperature.  The problem doesn't give you the radiative area of the three objects.  If the object with T$_1$ is smaller, it can have a lower total intensity than a cooler object.

I am more bothered by the description of the objects as "black bodies", but the shape of the spectrum deviates significantly from a blackbody curve.

Comment: What you said about the curve shape is correct but I don't think the radiative intensity depends on the area of the object. Radiative intensity is defined per unit area of the object so a body with larger area and one with smaller area will have the same total radiative intensity at the same temperature. It is the radiative power that will be greater for the object of bigger area. Am i right?

Comment: The question has issues and someone could raise objections about it.  But for me, the simplest rationalization is just that "intensity" is used in a colloquial sense.  It's easier to deal with than moving the peak.